# Failed to resolve package in Sencha Cmd

Tags: extjs, build, package, sencha-cmd, resolve

sencha cmd can not resolve required package with a specific version. the package is inside {{sencha repo}}/pkgs but when i try to build app, it says "Failed to resolve package my-package@a-specific-version".

Sencha Cmd version: 6.0.2.14
ExtJs: 6.0.0

Comment: For which package this error comes? Also post your cmd build error screenshot it will be helpful to investigate error.

Comment: It happens for the custom package i built, it's a code type package. there's nothing special about build error. [WRN] Failed to resolve package gam-commons@2.3.1.5

Comment: Try sencha app build classic command.

Comment: I already tried that. still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

your package must inside in WorkSpaceFolder/Package.

Comment: it's inside a workspace. here is the problem: i made a package called "commons", it's inside {workspace}/package/local. i added the package to sencha repo (repo/pkgs). when i change the version of the package to 1.1.0 and change the dependency of a project in workspace to commons@1.0.0 which is not inside workspace since i've changed the version to 1.1.0 and version 1.0.0 is inside sencha cmd local repo. it can't resolve it from there, seems that it looks just the workspace package dir.

Comment: Not entirely true. Package "repos" can exist elsewhere, but you need to add them using Sencha Cmd. I'm writing something up on the topic -- I'll link it soon.

Comment: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?307478-Failed-to-resolve-package&p=1124034#post1124034